# Identical classes with one properties type different

Tags: c#, .net

In my project I have implemented two identical classes where only one difference is type of one of the properties what can I do to avoid this code redundancy.

Comment: will it always be exactly two? or should it in theory work with any type? for the latter: generics, i.e. `class Foo<T> { public int Whatever {get;set;} public T TheOtherThing {get;set;}}`; but might not be the right fit if there are exactly two usages - then use `Foo<string>` and `Foo<DateTime>` (or whatever the usages are)

Comment: inheritance of the classes by keeping the same methods in one class and the child class having the extra property

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: Are you really sure they are representing similar enough concepts that you want to couple them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all of the common code in the two classes into a `public abstract class`. Create your two classes as:

```
public class ClassWithBool: MyAbstractClass
{
    public bool Property{ get; set;}
}
public class ClassWithInt: MyAbstractClass
{
    public int Property{ get; set;}
}
```

Alternatively, make it a generic class:

```
Public class MyClass<T>
{
// all code except your property

    public T Property{get;set;}
}
```